# using find and curl to upload a directory contents to Sonatype Nexus repository

Tags: bash, curl, nexus

I’m trying to use curl to upload a the contents of a directory to nexus via bash and am having a few issues in the command I’m using

In short I want to do a find command on a specific directory and use the –exec {} action to do a curl to nexus

However my find command returns the file path including the source directory and I want to change this so I only show the contents not the full path

e.g. say  I have a directory called trunk which contains these files and sub directories

```
trunk/directory1/file1
trunk/directory2/file1
trunk/directory2/file2
```

I want my find command to return

```
directory1/file1
directory2/file1
directory2/file2
```

then this can be passed to my exec command

my current find command is:-

```
find trunk -type f -exec curl --user user:pass --ftp-create-dirs -T {} https://PATH_TO_NEXUS/{} \;
```

this works ok except the files being created in nexus are

```
https://PATH_TO_NEXUS/trunk/directory1/file1
```

and what I want is

```
https://PATH_TO_NEXUS/directory1/file1
```

anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run your `find` command from inside the `trunk` directory:

```
cd trunk
find . -type f -exec curl --user user:pass --ftp-create-dirs -T {} https://PATH_TO_NEXUS/{} \;
```

Comment: how did I miss that? I got stuck into a pattern and completly forgot the basics. thanks for that