# How to upload a folder to Nexus?

Tags: nexus3

I got a repository in GitHub which we used to store 3rd party DLL's. I need to move this whole repo into Nexus and the repository has got many sub-folders in it. I want the same folder structure and the files into Nexus. I created raw repository in Nexus and uploaded few files manually. But it is time consuming and I might miss uploading some files. Is there a way that it can be automated? (versioning is not needed)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using find and curl to upload a directory contents to Sonatype Nexus repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417306/using-find-and-curl-to-upload-a-directory-contents-to-sonatype-nexus-repository)

Answer (score 2):

In a quickNdirty nutshell

```bash
user=your_username
password=your_password
nexus_uri=https://your.nexus.fqdn/
repo=name_of_your_raw_repo

git clone https://some.service/my_repo.git
cd my_repo

for f in $(find . -type f -name *.dll -printf "%P\n"); do
  curl -v -u ${user}:${password} --upload-file $f ${nexus_uri}/repository/${repo}/$f
done
```